# What is the reasons of using esb

Tags: apache-camel, esb, jbossfuse, jboss-tools, enterprise-integration

i am new in enterprice integration and esb concepts.

I am working a project which includes some integrations with different systems (like Sap, a file management system and this project will consume 14 external web services. I will create a web service project for to consume these external services).

I can write a web services which consume 14 external services and i can use these web services on my project. Why must i use an esb ? Which scenario

I want to understand that, when i must use a esb? what is the benefits in my case ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you read about 
Enterprise Integration Pattern

- http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/

and Apache Camel

- http://camel.apache.org/
- http://camel.apache.org/architecture.html

Comment: Thanks @simas_ch, i will read absolutely. I will use RH Jboss Fuse, i examined camel and i implemented basic poc projects. But i think, i did not make a decision about using esb for consume 14 external services. Creating a web services for consume these external services is very fast and known way. But, using fuse have a learnig curve. Is using esb really usefull for my scenario. What is your opinion about this case (using or not).

Comment: I know how it feels if one has to use Camel the first time. I would suggest to read about the reason for Enterprise Integration and then you will better understand what the advantage of using Camel is. Is this the only use case you have to implement or will there be more?

Comment: Only use case for now.  According to project design, it shows that, consuming 14 external service, integrating with Sap (a little module of sap) and integrating with a file management system. I will start to read your suggestions. Learing curve and conceps are strange but, I hope that using esb will benefit:)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JBoss Fuse, then there is a similar question and I answered it there. I would suggest you read the entire question and answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46291034/1382079

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, an ESB or whatever you want to call it, is expensive, not just financially but technically as well. Nobody uses it to consume 14 web services. It is often used as the central platform to connect multiple systems, both internally and externally to each other, ensuring that the systems are decoupled from each other. You need to calculate the ROI of having an ESB with your use case and upcoming projects.